# django doesn't serve user-uploaded files in production

Tags: django, nginx, django-templates, gunicorn, django-file-upload

I deployed a website with django. it servs all static files but doesn't serve user-uploaded files.
this is my `settings.py` and `urls.py`:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticroot')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

MEDIA_URL = '/files/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploaded_files')
```

and the `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),    
url(r'^$', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

In the pages, it prints user-uploaded files addresses correctly, but doesn't show them anf when I click on the links, it shows me 404 page.
I use last version of nginx that I took from nginx repositories. the version 1.12.
is it related to django or webserver(nginx+ gunicorn)? and how can I solve the problem?

***Update***
When I change the `MEDIA_URL` and `DEBUG` to True, for the first time it works and serves user-uploaded files, but if I refresh the page, then it doesn't work! what's the problem??

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the static and media files are not served by django in production. Thats why it works when you make DEBUG = True,

What you need to do is to setup an alias for media files in your nginx config for your site, inside your server block just like static files, like this:

```
    location /files/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/your/project/uploaded_files/;
    }
```

Also, dont forget to restart your nginx afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

you must define in **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
           url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),    
           url(r'^$', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
         ]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```